# How do I remove visible CRLFs in Notep;ad++?

Tags: notepad++

Using Notepad++ (sorry, I cannot find the version number, but it is the latest) with Python, suddenly visible CRLFs (white on black) appear in the text. They don't interfere with the functioning 0f the code, but they are very distracting. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Go to View --> Show Symbol --> Uncheck  "Show End of Line"